# Gifs displaying soft?

Tags: media

So I've ascertained wordpress does not compress gifs on upload. I've disabled multiple file size generation so gifs are displaying fullsize.

But the gif on my website is still displaying softer than a gif dragged directly from my desktop to a browser window. As per the attached screen grab.
I really need to correct this so any advice much appreciated.

thanks
Nigel.

[image]

Comment: it's not possible to answer this question with the information given, in all likelihood it's the browser doing this if the file is not being modified or resized, and this would make it a frontend/CSS issue not a WordPress issue. but again, right now it is not possible to answer the question without either significantly more information, or seeing it first hand

Comment: ok, thanks Tom. If you're able to help what information would you require to solve this?

Comment: we need to be able to see it directly, but the chances that it's within scope of this site are quite low, and it's super difficult to tell when all we have are screenshots and descriptions, there's no way to inspect or reproduce the problem. Also note that just because you changed the image resizing settings, doesn't mean WP went back and changed all the uploaded photos, those settings will only apply to new ones otherwise changing that setting could take days on some installs with thousands of images

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for replying.  Yeah I've been re uploading the files after making changes.  I've tracked the issue down to an issue with the theme assigning sizes to the thumbnails to fit the portfolio grid. It's a hack but if I regenerate my gif to match that size it works. I don't have a lot of experience with gifs but it seems they don't scale at all well either up or down.  sorry for the lack of info and thanks for your help. cheers nigel